# What does "He sets the rules in opposition" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, the-devils-advocate

Towards the end of *Devil's Advocate*, John Milton makes a long speech to Kevin. In part of this he gives Kevin an "inside information" into God and quotes:

> He gives man instincts. He gives you this extraordinary gift and then
>   what does He do? I swear, for His own amusement, His own private
>   cosmic gag reel, He sets the rules in opposition. It’s the goof of all
>   time. Look, but don’t touch. Touch, but don’t taste. Taste, don’t
>   swallow.

What exactly does he mean by "sets the rules in opposition", and the examples after as well eg. look but don't touch? I am guessing this is referring to rules of a religion since physically humans are obviously able to look and touch, touch and taste etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sets the rules in opposition" means that the rules that God set on humans are in the opposite of human nature, which was also given to humans by God.

So God gave us the instinct and ability to kill but told us not to kill. He made us as beings that crave lots of food but told us to not be gluttonous and only eat small amounts.

The rules set by God are the opposite of the way that God made humans act. If you want to obey the rules of God, you have to act the opposite of what your (God-given) instincts tell you to do.